# On jest, A worker process has failed to exit gracefully and has been force exited

Tags: node.js, jestjs, github-actions

When I run the unit test, I am getting the following warning.

**A worker process has failed to exit gracefully and has been force exited. This is likely caused by tests leaking due to improper teardown. Try running with --detectOpenHandles to find leaks. Active timers can also cause this, ensure that .unref() was called on them.**

When I use `--detectOpenHandles`, it gives me the following error.

[image]

To fix it, for now, I am using the following command on package.json scripts.

```
"test:ci": "jest --runInBand --forceExit"
```

However, I am not happy with the solution and still, I am getting the warning to use --detectOpenHandles.

It seems, the way I write the async test is wrong ? or how can fix it properly?

Note that, I have closed the database connection properly.

```
afterAll(async () => {
  if (mongo) {
    await mongo.stop();
  }
  mongoose.connection.close();
});
```

**The code of a unit test.**

```
import request from 'supertest';
import { app } from '../../app';

it('fails when a email that does not exist is supplied', async () => {
  await request(app)
    .post('/api/users/signin')
    .send({
      email: 'test@test.com',
      password: 'password',
    })
    .expect(400);
});

it('fails when an incorrect password is supplied', async () => {
  await request(app)
    .post('/api/users/signup')
    .send({
      email: 'test@test.com',
      password: 'password',
    })
    .expect(201);

  await request(app)
    .post('/api/users/signin')
    .send({
      email: 'test@test.com',
      password: 'aslkdfjalskdfj',
    })
    .expect(400);
});

it('responds with a cookie when given valid credentials', async () => {
  await request(app)
    .post('/api/users/signup')
    .send({
      email: 'test@test.com',
      password: 'password',
    })
    .expect(201);

  const response = await request(app)
    .post('/api/users/signin')
    .send({
      email: 'test@test.com',
      password: 'password',
    })
    .expect(200);

  expect(response.get('Set-Cookie')).toBeDefined();
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show the full code of your failed test case?

Comment: @n1md7, I have added the code to the description. Please look at it

Comment: In your screenshot `singin` failed and u added signup tests cases

Comment: @n1md7, Sorry for that. I have updated the code.

Comment: I'm encountering the same problem and am looking for a solution. This question would be more helpful if you posted the entire output as text instead of an screenshot that only shows part of the output.

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that your Express app does something at startup that is not being mocked in the test suite.

Perhaps it makes a real fetch call to another service to obtain info about the ecosystem, or connects to a redis instance, or some kind of log aggregator.

You probably need to review all the app code to figure out what external capabilities it depends on, and then ensure your test suite creates adequate shims so that the app can be reliably shut down during testing.

Sometimes an app server like this has an explicit shutdown function that its host container invokes when it receives a kill signal from the orchestrator. If your app has one, that function is probably as close to a list of external dependencies are you will find.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it was just a missing backslash in my app.js file.

So jest could not connect to the route, which is a dead end for the jest worker sending that request.

Try checking the routes in your app.js file